# Permission denied

Tags: r

I am having troubles in working with .csv files inside folders. I tried to give permission to R studio and execute as administrator but it did not work. Any suggestion?

```
"C:/Users/lokit/OneDrive/Escritorio/prices/" %>%
  dir_ls(recurse = TRUE) %>%
  as_tibble_col("path") %>% 
dplyr::mutate(data = purrr::map(path, function(path_i){
  
  data_i <- read_csv(path_i)
  
  if(str_detect(data_i$airline, "€")) {
    
    dplyr::rename(data_i, price = airline)
  }
  
  return(data_i) }))
```

```
Warnung: cannot open file 'C:/Users/lokit/OneDrive/Escritorio/prices/2022-01-20': Permission deniedError in `dplyr::mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `data = purrr::map(...)`.
Caused by error in `file()`:
! cannot open the connection
Backtrace:
  1. ... %>% ...
 12. vroom `<fn>`("C:/Users/lokit/OneDrive/Escritorio/prices/2022-01-20")
 13. vroom:::detect_compression(path)
 14. base::readBin(path, "raw", n = 6)
 15. base::file(con, "rb")
```

Comment: OneDrive itself can cause problems. Can you work with them in a directory that's fully local?

Comment: Are you use that's the name of the file? It's just a date? There's no extension on the file like `.csv` or anything? I would expect to see the full name in the error message

Comment: Or you probably want `dir_ls(recurse = TRUE, type="file")` to make sure you are only returning the files and not the directory names.

Comment: @GregorThomas I tried to do it but I got the same errorand there are a lot of  red **x** in the status in some files

Comment: @MrFlick There are `.csv` files inside the folders. The name of the folders are writen as date (e.g., 2022-06-22). I tried to make operation of the different files inside the 124 folders but I got the error specified above

Comment: The error is because you are passing a folder name to `read_csv`, use `dir_ls(recurse = TRUE, type="file")` to only get the files.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you. You saved me for the second time today